# Reflexive implies short exact sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, sheaf-cohomology

For a unitary algebra $A$, i.e. an algebra with identity(if necessary we can assume it is commutative), let $M$ denote an $A$-module of finite type. It is **reflexive**, if  $$M^{**}\cong M,$$ where $M^*=\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,A)$.

> **Q**: For a finite type $A$-module $M$ which is reflexive can we construct a short exact sequence
>   $$E_0\to E_1\to M^*\to0,$$
>   where $E_0$ is a free $A$-modules and $E_1$ is a torsion-free module ?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what's $A$: what's "a unitary algebra"? An algebra over a field? Is $A$ commutative or not?

Comment: To be precise, a module is reflexive if the natural map $M\to M^{**}$ is an isomorphism. The two things cannot be equal.